# How to add image from local folder in the state of my react component?

Tags: reactjs, slider, carousel, e-commerce

here is the code and I want to add images from my local folders instead of item#1,2,3,...
how can I do that?
besides if anyone of you knows a good source code for creating product slider please let me know thank you.

```
import Carousel from 'react-elastic-carousel';

class ProductSlider extends Component {
  state = {
    items: [
      {id: 1, image: 'item #1'},
      {id: 2, image: 'item #2'},
      {id: 3, image: 'item #3'},
      {id: 4, image: 'item #4'},
      {id: 5, image: 'item #5'}
    ]
  }

  render () {
    const { items } = this.state;
    return (
      <Carousel>
        {items.map(item => <div key={item.id}>{item.image}</div>)}
      </Carousel>
    )
  }
}
export default ProductSlider;
```

Comment: I think that better way is to store  images' url in state. I don't think so that is possible to have image inside state when image doesn't exist in DOM. Probably you should have images urls list, then add <img> tag with this urls and after images loaded you can query them and store in state if you really need these there.

Comment: but I just have them in my pc , can I somehow store them  somewhere and use the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are building app with create-react-app.  one of the easiest way to import image is to use `public` folder. place your image into public and write your code like this.

1. make `public` folder in your project's root path
2. place your images into public folder

```
public
├── 1.png
├── 2.png
├── 3.png
└── 4.png
```

```
import Carousel from 'react-elastic-carousel';

class ProductSlider extends Component {
  state = {
    items: [
      {id: 1, image: '/1.png'},
      {id: 2, image: '/2.png'},
      {id: 3, image: '/3.png'},
      ...
    ]
  }

  render () {
    const { items } = this.state;
    return (
      <Carousel>
        {items.map(item => <div key={item.id}><img src={item.image} alt='fill something' /></div>)}
      </Carousel>
    )
  }
}
export default ProductSlider;
```

you can find more about public folder from this document.
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/